Limit of the ratio of two survival functions
Result: A result in asymptotic theory says the following: Let $Y$ be a real random variable with full support. Assume:
A1)  $E(|Y|)<\infty$.
A2)  $$\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\Pr(Y\geq y)}{\Pr(Y\geq \kappa h(y))}=1$$ for some $\kappa>0$ and function $h$ such that $\lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} h'(y)=1$.
Then, $\kappa=1$

I would like to claim that the same result but now replacing assumption A2) with A3):
A3) $$  \lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\Pr(Y\leq y)}{\Pr(Y\leq \kappa h(y))}=1$$
for some $\kappa>0$ and function $h$ such that $\lim_{y\rightarrow - \infty} h'(y)=1$.
Differently from 2), in 3), I send $y$ to $-\infty$ and consider the left tail of $Y$.
Question: Does the result still hold under 1) and 3)? If not, how should I change the sufficient  conditions?

Let $\tilde Y=-Y$ and $\tilde y=-y$. Then your condition A3) says that
$$
1=\lim_{y\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\Pr(Y\leq y)}{\Pr(Y\leq \kappa h(y))}=
=\lim_{\tilde y\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\Pr(-\tilde Y\leq -\tilde y)}{\Pr(-\tilde Y\leq \kappa h(-\tilde y))}=
\lim_{\tilde y\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\Pr(\tilde Y\geq \tilde y)}{\Pr(\tilde Y\geq -\kappa h(-\tilde y))}
$$
so to apply the previous theorem, you need
$$
\lim_{\tilde y\to\infty} \frac{d}{d\tilde y}[-h(-\tilde y)]=1 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad h'(-\tilde y)\to 1\text{ as }\tilde y\to\infty \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad h'(y)\to 1\text{ as }y\to-\infty
$$  which is similar, but not the same condition on $h$ as in A2).

$E(|Y|)<\infty$ is still OK?

Yes, of course as $E(|Y|)=E(|\tilde Y|)$.
